# Error when calling read.xlsx

Tags: r

I am trying to read an excel file using R,

```
download.file("https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.xls?accessType=DOWNLOAD","test2.xls")
cameraData <- read.xlsx("test2.xls", sheetIndex = 1)
```

but I get the following error:

`Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  :java.io.IOException: block[ 0 ] already removed - does your POIFS have circular or duplicate block references?`

All required packages are successful unpacked (rJava, xlsxjars, xlsx)

R version:

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to provide the code that has thrown this error.

Comment: + the excel file if possible (i.e. make the error reproducible).

Comment: Code used is added to the post.

Comment: I tried the `download.file` but the file downloaded does not even open with Excel.

Comment: That is correct, the download file using R download.file cannot be opened... But if I donwload it using chrome, I can open it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a missing parameter in the download.file call:
mode="wb"

So, calling

```
download.file("https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.xls?accessType=DOWNLOAD","test2.xls", mode="wb")
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sessionInfo() to make sure library(xlsx) is loaded. File downloaded and saved to working directory. Opened fine in Open Office and loaded fine in r session.
HTH